# Postgresql returning the most popular genre of product per customer

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that is supposed to return a list of customers with the most popular product type for each customer. I have have a query that sums up each product purchased in all given product types and lists them in descending order per customer

```
SELECT c.customer_name as cname, ptr.product_type as pop_gen, sum(od.quantity) as li
FROM product_type_ref as ptr
INNER JOIN product as p 
    on p.product_type_ref_id = ptr.product_type_ref_id
INNER JOIN order_detail as od
    on od.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN order as o
    on o.order_id = od.order_id
INNER JOIN customer as c 
    on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY cname, pop_gen
ORDER BY cname, li DESC
```

which returns this data:

```
'andy','Drama',1000
'andy','Action',250
'andy','Comedy',100
'bebe','Drama',250
'bebe','Action',100
'bebe','Comedy',25
'buster','Action',825
'buster','Comedy',768
'buster','Drama',721
'buster','Romance',100
'ron','Romance',50
'ron','Comedy',10
```

how could i return this:

```
andy, Drama
bebe, Drama
buster, Action
ron, Romance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic `greatest-n-per-group`. One possible solution is to use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        c.customer_name as cname, ptr.product_type as pop_gen, sum(od.quantity) as li
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.customer_name ORDER BY sum(od.quantity) DESC) AS rn
    FROM 
        product_type_ref as ptr
        INNER JOIN product as p on p.product_type_ref_id = ptr.product_type_ref_id
        INNER JOIN order_detail as od on od.product_id = p.product_id
        INNER JOIN order as o on o.order_id = od.order_id
        INNER JOIN customer as c on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
    GROUP BY 
        cname, pop_gen
)
SELECT
    cname, pop_gen, li
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY cname;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can just use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.customer_name) c.customer_name as cname,
       ptr.product_type as pop_gen, sum(od.quantity) as li
FROM product_type_ref as ptr
INNER JOIN product as p 
    on p.product_type_ref_id = ptr.product_type_ref_id
INNER JOIN order_detail as od
    on od.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN order as o
    on o.order_id = od.order_id
INNER JOIN customer as c 
    on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY cname, pop_gen
ORDER BY cname, li DESC;
```

Comment: using distinct doesn't guarantee that toy get the row with the highest sum value.

Comment: @StillLearningToCode . . . This isn't `DISTINCT` it is `DISTINCT ON`.  It uses the `ORDER BY` clause to select one row for each `cname` -- in this case, the one with the largest `li` value.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT c.customer_name as cname, 
               ptr.product_type as pop_gen, 
               sum(od.quantity) as li,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.customer_name
                                  ORDER BY sum(od.quantity) DESC) as rn
       ......
     ) as T
WHERE T.rn = 1
```

Comment: Should `pop_gen` really be part of `PARTITION`? I don't think so.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Now Im second guess myself. Will need create a test query to be sure.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Add it  Fiddle. Work as expected

Comment: The general principle is simple: you need one row per `customer_name`, so `ROW_NUMBER` should be partitioned by `customer_name` only.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov That part was clear. My doubt was how will  order by `SUM(quantity)` will work.  But in that case the data is already group by `TYPE` on the outside query and that is the data inside the partition